# ¿Como se en que rango de fecha me encuentro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Tengo un calendario hecho con el `fullcalendar`, quisiera saber si hay un evento que me ayude a detectar en que rango de fecha me encuentro, que este evento se ejecute cada vez que cambio de fecha, bien si hago clic en la lista de "semana", "mes", "dia", etc, cualquiera de los items de la cabecera del calendario.

Ej de un calendar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var datos = [{
    "id": 27,
    "numero": 700022,
    "fecha": "2017-03-09",
    "color": "#ffff00",
    "hora_inicio": "00:00:00",
    "hora_final": "05:59:00",
    "codigo": "14523",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Inyectable 154 ml",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "L\u00edquidos Esteriles"
  }, {
    "id": 13,
    "numero": 700009,
    "fecha": "2017-03-02",
    "color": "#ffff00",
    "hora_inicio": "00:00:00",
    "hora_final": "05:59:00",
    "codigo": "14523",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Inyectable 154 ml",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "L\u00edquidos Esteriles"
  }, {
    "id": 11,
    "numero": 700006,
    "fecha": "2017-03-08",
    "color": "#ffff00",
    "hora_inicio": "00:00:00",
    "hora_final": "05:59:00",
    "codigo": "14523",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Inyectable 154 ml",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "L\u00edquidos Esteriles"
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "numero": 700007,
    "fecha": "2017-03-07",
    "color": "#ff0000",
    "hora_inicio": "13:00:00",
    "hora_final": "16:59:00",
    "codigo": "14523",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Inyectable 154 ml",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "L\u00edquidos Esteriles"
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "numero": 700003,
    "fecha": "2017-03-08",
    "color": "#0000ff",
    "hora_inicio": "06:00:00",
    "hora_final": "11:59:00",
    "codigo": "14523",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Inyectable 154 ml",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "L\u00edquidos Esteriles"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "numero": 700002,
    "fecha": "2017-03-08",
    "color": "#ffff00",
    "hora_inicio": "00:00:00",
    "hora_final": "05:59:00",
    "codigo": "14523",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Inyectable 154 ml",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "L\u00edquidos Esteriles"
  }, {
    "id": 14,
    "numero": 700010,
    "fecha": "2017-03-07",
    "color": "#0000ff",
    "hora_inicio": "06:00:00",
    "hora_final": "11:59:00",
    "codigo": "10000",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Jarabe 155 gg",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "Solidos"
  }, {
    "id": 21,
    "numero": 700016,
    "fecha": "2017-03-09",
    "color": "#ff0000",
    "hora_inicio": "13:00:00",
    "hora_final": "16:59:00",
    "codigo": "10000",
    "productos_nombres": "Miovit",
    "concat_presentacion": "Jarabe 155 gg",
    "lineas_de_produccion": "Solidos"
  }];

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month listDay,listWeek,listMonth,listYear'
    },
    views: {
      listDay: {
        buttonText: 'Listado: Día'
      },
      listWeek: {
        buttonText: 'Listado: Semana'
      },
      listMonth: {
        buttonText: 'Listado: Mes'
      },
      listYear: {
        buttonText: 'Listado: Año'
      }
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
      var events = [];
      if (datos) {
        $.map(datos, function(v) {
          events.push({
            id: v.id,
            title: v.numero,
            start: v.fecha + ' ' + v.hora_inicio,
            end: v.fecha + ' ' + v.hora_final,
            button: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Datos del Producto" data-content="Nombre: ' + v.productos_nombres + '<br />Presentación: ' + v.concat_presentacion + '<br />Linea de Producción: ' + v.lineas_de_produccion + '">' + v.codigo + '</button>',
            //url: '#',
            backgroundColor: v.color, //color de la db
            borderColor: "#000", // borde negro
            color: '#000',
            textColor: invertColor(v.color) // invierto el color para q se aprecie el texto
          });
        });
      }
      callback(events);
    },
  });
});



function invertColor(hexTripletColor) {
  var color = hexTripletColor;
  color = color.substring(1); // remove #
  color = parseInt(color, 16); // convert to integer
  color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color; // invert three bytes
  color = color.toString(16); // convert to hex
  color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); // pad with leading zeros
  color = "#" + color; // prepend #
  return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mejorar la redacción de tu pregunta? Personalmente no entiendo qué tratas de decir.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía requiero de hacer un contador, pero el contador que lo calcule a partir de lo que esta mostrando en la vista, para ellos requiero saber cual es el inicio y cual es el final que esta apreciando el usuario, es decir, si esta en el mes de Marzo, en la opción de Marzo deberia de obtener inicio 1-3-2017 hasta 30-3-2017. Si esta semanal debería de obtener inicio 6-3-2017 hasta 12-3-2017. Esto los necesito para enviarlos por ajax y en backend hace un between en sql

Comment: osea, ¿quieres obtener el primer y ultimo dia de un mes dado y el primer dia y ultimo dia de una semana dada?

Comment: @EmanuelVe el primer y ultimo dia que el usuario este visualizando el usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la fecha inicio y final que el usuario esta visualizando se puede obtener de la siguiente manera:

```
var calendar = $('#calendario').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
var view = calendar.view;
console.debug(view.start._d);
console.debug(view.end._d);
```

Lo único que no consigo hacer es capturar el evento de cambio de vista del `fullcalendar`.

Para obtener el evento de visualización en la que el usuario esta (dia, semana, mes. etc) lo hacemos de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar({
    ...
    viewRender: function(view, element) { alert('new view: ' + view.name); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
$('#miCalendario').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') //Fecha inicial de la vista actual
$('#miCalendario').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') //Fecha final de la vista actual
```

Si no te devuelve la fecha en el formato que necesitas, entonces puedes hacer uso de "moment" así:

```
moment($('#miCalendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
moment($('#miCalendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Con moment puedes cambiar el formato a conveniencia, ejemplo: `.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') //Para un formato de fecha más completo`

Si los rangos de fechas de cada vista los requieres para hacer una consulta a la BD mediante POST ó GET, entonces te recomiendo usar "eventSources" que dispone de los parámetros "startParam" y "endParam".